# Unable to make remote connections to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, tcp

I have a SQL Server instance installed on my VPS I've followed all the usual steps to connect remotely including:

- Allowing Remote Connections
- Enabling TCP/IP + adding port 1433 to the IPAll range
- Creating a Firewall rule to enable the connection

Still no luck though I always get the error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns outt he problem was that I hadn't allowed the SQL Server Browser through the Windows Firewall on Windows Server 2008.

So to fix:

Add an exception for the SQL Server Browser. (udp port 1434)

Answer (score 0):

you must check that also all the following

- check the protocol `named pipes` is `enabled`
- the IP port for `named pipes` is enabled (usually port# 445)
- the `SQL Server Browser service` is started

Comment: Tried to restart the service to apply the changes and the SQL server service will not restart because it will not respond in a timely fashion - also how do I find the IP port for the named pipes?

Comment: 1. Are you trying to restart the server from the server itself? 2. IP Port for `named pipes` 99% chances are ports#  445 or 135 just try them.

Comment: Trying to restart it from the SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: it happened to me that I had a couple of servers that I couldn't restart the SQL Server service from the SQL Configuration Manager and from the Service panel, and got that error.
usually the only way I could restart the service was from SSMS logged in as sa or the same user that installed the SQL server.
I don't remember if I solved the problem, or just used the same user that created the server.

Comment: Managed to start the service but still not working - even after all the steps above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34812/discussion-between-luis-ll-and-liane-stevenson)